# I search for user idle plugin/decision for livewire / alpine app

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

Are there something like https://github.com/soixantecircuits/idle-vue ( detects when the user hasn't
interacted with your app for a while) compatible with
laravel 7 /livewire 1.3 / turbolinks:5 / alpine@v2 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got `idle-js` installed somehow, you can do:

```html
<div
  x-data="{ idle: false }"
  x-init="_idle = new IdleJs({
    onIdle: () => { idle = true },
    onActive: () => { idle = false },
  });
  _idle.start();"
>
  <p x-text="idle ? 'Idle': 'Not idle'"></p>
</div>
```

I've got it working as [a codepen](https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/QWNyqvz)

Comment: What is idle-js ?  this https://github.com/shawnmclean/Idle.js/ ?

Comment: Yep that's the one, I've used a CDN include (see the JS section of the codepen)

Comment: Thanks! looks like it is triggered on idle... Also can you give me a hint how can I run from js code method livewire:logout ?

Comment: For that you'll probably need to dispatch a custom event from Alpine and then listen to it from Livewire? I'm not too familiar but I'm not sure how Alpine-Livewire interop works